# How to update item without recreating the whole list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically, from an API request, I have an array containing catalogs with a list of items which can be favorited.
I display them using three main React components with hooks:

- `Live` which makes the API request, stores the catalogs in state, and display one `Catalog` at a time
- `Catalog` which receives items as a prop and a `handleFavorite` function and displays a list of `Item`
- `Item` which receives an item as props and the `handleFavorite` function and displays a *like* or *dislike* button

Is there any way I can modify the `favorited` property of a single item in the `Catalog` component using hooks? Otherwise, since the catalogues are stored in state in the `Live` component, does that mean I have to recreate the whole array of catalogues every time I have to update one item in one catalog?

There could be a few thousand items in all catalogs combined so it doesn't seem like a good way to handle that. I also thought about `useContext` but that doesn't seem to be what it's meant for.

Comment: Yes, sure, you can use react hooks to hold state and issue effects in functional components, like updating state. Yes, it is the standard pattern to shallowly copy the entire array of data into a new array object reference even when updating a single element.

Answer (score 1):

In `Catalog` component you could use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). I quate from react official web site.

> useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

Read more about useMemo [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: Having read the doc of `useMemo` I'm not sure how it applies in this case as I don't expect items to be updated on every render

Comment: @Halhex With useMemo each time it checks a prop and if a prop is not changed then render does not happen.

Comment: Yeah but I'm asking about having to recreate the whole array of catalogs because of one item being updated here, not about rendering